# Finding the equation of the plane that touch in the plane $z=g(x,y)$ in the point $(-6,9,-6)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(u,v),u(x,y),v(x,y)$ functions with continioas partial derivativs in evary point such that:

$u(-6,9)=-5\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\nabla u(-6,9)=6 \hat i-4 \hat j$

$v(-6,9)=-9\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\nabla v(-6,9)=- \hat i+ \hat j$

$f(-5,9)=-6\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\nabla u(-5,-9)=5 \hat i+8 \hat j$

Let define $g(x):=f\bigg(u(x,y),v(x,y)\bigg)$

So the equation of the plane that touch in the plane $z=g(x,y)$ in the point $(-6,9,-6)$

> is $z=$______$x+$_________$y+$_________

Sorry about my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation of tangent plan is given by
 $$z-g(x_0,y_0)=f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0) + f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$
so 
 $$z=g(x_0,y_0)+ f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0) + f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)\\=
g(-6,9)+ f_x(u(-6,9),v(-6,9))(x+6) + f_y(u(-6,9),v(-6,9))(y-9)\\=
-6+ f_x(-5,-9)(x+6) + f_y(-5,-9)(y-9)\\=
-6+ 5(x+6) + 8(y-9)$$